# Gmail API node js - gapi not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am using the following function from Google Gmail APIs to get all messages from users

```
/**
 * Retrieve Messages in user's mailbox matching query.
 *
 * @param  {String} userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
 * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
 * @param  {String} query String used to filter the Messages listed.
 * @param  {Function} callback Function to call when the request is 
complete.
 */
function listMessages(userId, query, callback) {
var getPageOfMessages = function(request, result) {
    request.execute(function(resp) {
        result = result.concat(resp.messages);
        var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
        if (nextPageToken) {
            request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
                'userId': userId,
                'pageToken': nextPageToken,
                'q': query
            });
            getPageOfMessages(request, result);
        } else {
            callback(result);
        }
    });
};
var initialRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
    'userId': userId,
    'q': query
});
getPageOfMessages(initialRequest, []);
}
```

I get the following error:

> var initialRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
> ^
> ReferenceError: gapi is not defined

I tried replacing `gapi` with `google` since I have initialized `var google` for api module but that didn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try using `window.gapi` or `global.gapi`

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht that neither worked :(

Comment: @Arihant you should include the library to your code

Comment: @LEQADA which Library are you talking about? I already have the following included: 

var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

Comment: @Arihant I'm talking about the `gapi` in your code. Where you initialize it? I have a feeling that it should be a library defined somewhere. You can't just start to use some variable which never was defined.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.. 
GAPI is used for Client-side javascript only, **not server side with Nodejs**.

1) After you set up the sample from Node.js Quickstart
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

2) Try to use this function to **List** and **Get** the recent email from your account:

```
function getRecentEmail(auth) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth });
  gmail.users.messages.list({ auth: auth, userId: 'me', maxResults: 1, q: 'subject:()' }, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }

    // Get the message id which we will need to retreive tha actual message next.
    var message_id = response['data']['messages'][0]['id'];

    // Retreive the actual message using the message id
    gmail.users.messages.get({ auth: auth, userId: 'me', 'id': message_id }, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      // console.log(response['data']);

      var to = response['data']['payload']['headers'][4].value;
      var from = response['data']['payload']['headers'][5].value;
      var subject = response['data']['payload']['headers'][6].value;
      var email_body_raw = response['data']['payload']['body']['data'];

      // Convert encoded email body message into human readable text message
      data = email_body_raw;
      buff = new Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
      email_body_readable = buff.toString();

      console.log('content:\n' + email_body_readable + '\n__________\nto: ' + to + '\nfrom: ' + from + '\nsubject: ' + subject + '\n__________\n');
    });
  });
}


fs.readFile('credentials.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  //authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendMessage);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), getRecentEmail);
});
```

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Hope this helps!